# Using ranges in formula in Excel

Tags: excel, date, countif

I will give you an example right away. I have dates in a column (F) as text in this format. `Jan 31, 2014 12:55 PM PST`

I can convert these to dates using `DATEVALUE((LEFT(F5,12))),`

But I want to do this conversion on the fly when I am using this range as an argument for a countif function:

```
=COUNTIF(Dates!$F:$F,">"&DATE(1,1,2014))
```

:this obviously doesn't work since I have the date as text in that column

Let's say I converted these dates in another column G using `DATEVALUE((LEFT(F5,12))),`

```
=COUNTIF(Dates!$G:$G,">"&DATE(1,1,2014))
```

:Now this would work

But I want something like (which doesn't work)

```
=COUNTIF(DATEVALUE(LEFT(Dates!$F:$F,12)),">"&DATE(1,1,2014))
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work:

```
=SUM(IF(DATEVALUE(LEFT(F:F,12)) > DATE(1,1,2014),1,0))
```

entered as a "array formula" (using ctrl-shift-enter).

Comment: Floris, when any cell in `F:F` is empty or in wrong format, `DATEVALUE` returns `#VALUE!` and result would be `#VALUE!`. However this one works `=SUM(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(LEFT(F:F,12)) > DATE(2014,1,1),0)*1)`, and also as I know correct syntax is `DATE( year, month, day )` :)

Comment: =SUM(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(LEFT(AV_Registration!$F$2:$F$2500,12)) > DATE(2013,1,1),0)*1)

This works, but how can I add a ceiling date, (check the dates between 2014,1,1 and 2014,2,1

Comment: @user3380958 - if you have multiple conditions, you can multiply the `IF` statements together. `SUM(IF(condition1,1,0)*IF(condition2,1,0))` with all the error trapping etc will apply both conditions since you only get a `1` when corresponding elements are both true: `0*0=0, 0*1=0, 1*0=0, 1*1=1`. So multiplication is like doing "AND".

Comment: @simoco - thanks for pointing out both those things. I had copied the `DATE` bit straight from the original question...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `COUNTIF` because the first argument of `COUNTIF` must be a range (and using your DATEVALUE function will give an "array"). You can use `SUMPRODUCT` - I recommend restricting the range rather than using the whole column, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((DATEVALUE(LEFT(Dates!$F2:$F1000,12))>DATE(1,1,2014))+0)`

Comment: I would also add `IFERROR(DATEVALUE(...),0)` since when cell is empty (or in wrong format), `DATEVALUE` returns `#VALUE!`. And also not sure whe OP uses `DATE(1,1,2014)`, but correct syntax `DATE( year, month, day )` (at least in msdn)

Comment: This works as long as the array we set (1-1000) is fully defined.  my array is increasing everyday. If I choose an array that contains blank values I get #value error.

Comment: @user3380958, yes you need error checking......but I won't pursue that here, I see you have an answer from Floris  - simoco, I didn't notice the date - of course DATE(1,1,2014) gives a vaild date.....7/7/1906, not the intent I suppose!